# Learning `while`/`until` statements

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to return the phrase `Wig Wam` four times using `while/until`. How would I describe the condition that is satisfied after four times, and return?

```
counter = 6
loop do
  counter = counter + 1
  puts "Wig Wam"
  if counter >= 10
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: small tip unrelated to the main question is that `counter += 1` would be shorthand in Ruby for `counter = counter + 1`

Comment: As you may know, the Ruby way is to use an enumerator with a block: `4.times { puts "Wig Wam" }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same idea, using the while.

```
counter = 6

while counter < 10 
 counter = counter + 1
 puts "Wig Wam"    
end
```

Also keep in mind that the 2 constructs are different in that one always executes at least one while the other one relies on the condition.

Alternative ways:

```
counter = 6

begin 
 counter = counter + 1
 puts "Wig Wam"    
end while counter < 10
```

OR

```
4.times { puts "Wig Wham" }
```

Answer (score 0):

It all has to do with what kind of logical comparison you use. With `while` you are going to need to use `<=`, but with `until` you'll want to use `==`. If you say it out loud in English you can easily get a feel for what is appropriate in each case. "While counter is less than or equal to 4, put the statement" vs. "Until counter equals 4, put the statement."

```
while counter <= 4
  puts 'Wig Wam'
  counter += 1
end

until counter == 4
  puts 'Wig Wam'
  counter += 1
end
```